# Eclipse RCP MessageBox.open don't work on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, gtk, eclipse-rcp, messagebox

as the title says, when I when i call the method `open` of a `MessageBox` instance, nothing happens.
This is the code:

```
Shell dialog = new Shell(SWT.TITLE | SWT.BORDER | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL | SWT.ON_TOP);
shell.open();
```

In this dialog some actions let me open this message box:

```
MessageBox box = new MessageBox(dialog, SWT.ICON_WARNING | SWT.OK);
box.setText("Warning");
box.setMessage(label);
box.open();
```

I'm using Eclipse Indigo 3.7.2 for RCP and RAP Developers on Ubuntu 11.10 with Unity (Ubuntu2D) and Compiz 0.9.6, with OpenJDK 1.7.0_147. [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/67643) and [here](http://mou.me.uk/2009/10/31/fixing-eclipse-in-ubuntu-9-10-karmic-koala/) are some tips to solve this problem, (fixed by setting the environment variable `GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS`), but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it. For some reasons, under Linux the message boxes are drawn *under* the components created with the flag `SWT.ON_TOP` (under Windows the messages boxes are *always* above any component). I just removed the `SWT.ON_TOP` from the parent dialog and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could include some more information about your run configuration and what language you are using, although I assume java.... In addition, you didn't bother to load the whole code, only a fragment. If the code was relatively short, 500 lines or less, post it on codepad or something.

But if this is a java project, that's now how you show a message box. Look here for that:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, my project is a Java project. Swing works perfectly, but I have to use the SWT library.

Answer (score 0):

Use new standart message dialogs

```java
org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog
```

```java
MessageDialog.openConfirm(shell, "Confirm", "Please confirm");
MessageDialog.openError(shell, "Error", "Error occured");
MessageDialog.openInformation(shell, "Info", "Info for you");
MessageDialog.openQuestion(shell, "Question", "Really, really?");
MessageDialog.openWarning(shell, "Warning", "I warn you");
```